# Page is reloading without response in node.js and in the web console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js

The console.log("After Function") is executed but console.log("getUserByUsername is called") is not executed and the page remains reloading and NO error log is given, this problems happens to me in many cases and I can't find the reason why.

```
const Coach = require('./src/models/coache');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'},
  (email, password, done) => {
    console.log("After Function");
    Coach.getUserByUsername(email, (err, user) => {
      console.log("getUserByUsername is called");                    
    });
  })
);
```

here is the Coach.getUserByUsername function:

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = (email, callback) => {
  CoachesModel.findOne({
    where: {email: email}
  }, callback);
}
```

here is the whole program:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'},
  (email, password, done) => {
    console.log("After Function");
    Coach.getUserByUsername(email, (err, user) => {
      console.log("getUserByUsername is called");
      if (err) throw err;
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown User' });
      }
      Coach.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (isMatch) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
        }
      });
    });
  })
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  Coach.getUserById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/profile', failureRedirect: '/users/login', failureFlash: true}),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/profile');
  });
```

Comment: Do have some kind of `res` object in your code with has some kind of callback functions? Because it doesn't look like as you are returning something to the client. Which framework are you using?

Comment: I added the whole bunch of code, check it

Comment: I'am using express, passport-local, and mysql

Comment: Do the URLs `/login`, `/test` and `/users/login` exist on the server?

Comment: the action of the form is /login, /test is just for test and /users/login exists

Comment: But error 404 would mean exactly that. After the login there is a redirect to either the successfull or failure page. And if the URL does not exist you get a 404 error.

Comment: I changed /test to a one exists but in-vain

Comment: If the problem is related to the redirection, I should get (cannot get /test) but the page is reloading with only executing the findOne() first part which is executing  the query